# Getting US visa for a job meeting

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens, applications, business-travel

I am a self-taught software developer been working online for a while. I've been building a software for an employee in a company and getting paid through Paypal.

The company now decides to buy the product, employ me full-time (remote) however they'd like me to go for a meeting to the US.

What is the best way to get a visa for it? Should they invite me or write some kind of an invitation letter? Should I apply to it by my-self?

Some info about me:

- The university I finished is completely another field (will that rise an eyebrow?)
- I assume they'll cover all my expenses being there.
- I am a UK citizen but haven't lived there for the past 4 years. Been traveling/working from home in Europe.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As a UK citizen, you are eligible for [Visa Waiver Program](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html) entry:

> The Visa Waiver Program (VWP) enables most citizens or nationals of participating countries* to travel to the United States for tourism or business for stays of 90 days or less without obtaining a visa.

The permitted activities include:

> Business:
>
> - consult with business associates

All you need to do is apply for an [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/), book your tickets, and go. No invitation letter or other documentation is necessary.

Comment: Do you need to bring additional documents with you during travel?

Comment: Nothing. It's dead easy.  You state the words "I'm going for a meeting".  It is absolutely permitted to go for a meeting!

Comment: One small clarification:  you might get freaked out by some wording in the VWP that you cannot "seek work in the US".  Don't be.  That crappy piece of writing is meant to say that you cannot perform paid work in the USA without the appropriate visa (nor seek to do so).  You CAN try to get people to hire you legally in the US -- that's totally a valid use of the visa waiver.

Comment: @Mark_Anderson I don't understand this: I cannot seek work, but I can try to get people to hire me? What's the difference?

Comment: @FabioTurati It's the difference between being getting a job in the US (not allowed) and getting a job for a US company that will be done in your home country (allowed).  Attending meetings is not seen as work by immigration.

Comment: @FabioTurati: Sorry for the confusion -- you can't be seeking to perform work illegally.  You are allowed to try and seek a LEGAL job in the USA.

If that's not clear, consider that the govt is very clear that working without a visa is bad.  But catching you doing such work is kind of hard, so they give themselves a bit of extra slack and say "you can't be trying to get illegal work".  

On the flipside, paid work with appropriate visas is great.  Bonus taxes, generally highly skilled, highly paid workers etc...  So the govt is happy to let people try to get that work.

Comment: @DanNeely:  I think this might be a typo on you end, but trying to get a job in the US is allowed IF that job offer comes with an appropriate visa.  ie. A UK national is allowed to try and get a job in the USA, so long as the intent is to get a job that provides a work visa.  The banned part is intending to seek illegal work.

Comment: @Mark_Anderson more that I was trying to limit the question the the type of visa being discussed, but hadn't considered the case of coming for an interview and returning with a different visa to work vs coming on a normal business visa interviewing successfully and starting to work without getting additional approval.

Answer (score 63):

Greg Hewgill's answer is correct, but one caveat: do not talk to the immigration officer about doing any work in the US.  A series of business meetings is fine, but the VWP does not allow you to work in the US for money.  It is fine to bring your laptop to take notes on at the meeting or to show the immigration officer the work that you are doing (in Europe), but legally you are not allowed to (for example) code for an hourly wage between meetings or in the evenings in your hotel.  If you mention you plan to work while in the US, you may be denied entry and possibly will become ineligible for the VWP in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I am not willing to do paid work in my visit, just the meeting

Comment: Let's double-emphasise this answer since one has come up of a similar nature before - the phrasing is important and the word 'work' as in "I am here with work" is likely to cause you trouble even if your intent is obvious.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The correct word to use in cases like this is always "business", **never** "work".